# Why does static array did not work with JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

```
@Service
public class Executor {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void deleteRows(Long[] ids, String table) {
 
            entityManager.createNativeQuery("update " + table + "  set flag =0 where id in ?1 ")
                    .setParameter(1, ids).executeUpdate();
}
}
```

The flag field is boolean.

When call the method deleteRows([1,2,3],"test_table");

the stack exception that I can't understand

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'x'ACED0005757200115B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E4C6F6E673B7DE10AB2BBBC632B020000787000' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter in the IN clause needs to be a `Collection` not an array. So you have to convert your array to lets say a `List` prior setting it as parameter to the query. Also please note that depending your Hibernate version you might need to enclose into parenthesis "(", ")" your IN clause e.g. `where id in (?1)`

```
@Transactional
public void deleteRows(Long[] ids, String table) {
     List<Long> idsList = Arrays.asList(ids);
     entityManager.createNativeQuery("update " + table + "  set flag =0 where id in ?1 ").setParameter(1, idsList ).executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If @pleft answer doesn't work, you could try this:

```java
@Transactional
    public void deleteRows(Long[] ids, String table) {
 
            entityManager.createNativeQuery("update " + table + "  set flag =0 where id in (:parameter)")
                    .setParameter("parameter", ids).executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Adriel 
But This gives another error.
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect BINARY value: 'x'aced0005757200115b4c6a6176612e6c616e672e4c6f6e673b7de10ab2bbbc632b0200007870000000017372000e6a6176612e6c616e672e4c6f6e673b8be4' ...